# How to upload multiple documents into project folder using Angular.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need to store different types of documents inside the project folder in single button click using Angular.js and PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
var fileData={'image':file,'regdoc':regDocs,'compRegDoc':compRegDocs};

$scope.upload=Upload.upload({
            url: 'php/uploadAll.php',
            method:'POST',
            file: fileData
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('file',data);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
            console.log('err file',data);
    })
```

> uploadALL.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){    
    $errors= array();        
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];   
    $file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");        
    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
         header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
         $errors[]="image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        $errors[]='File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        //$today=('date')(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../upload/".$file_name);
        echo " uploaded file: " . "upload/" . $file_name;
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
else{
    $errors= array();
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    $errors[]="No image found";
    print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

Here I have one image and the other two are .pdf/docx type files. When the user clicks the submit button these 3 files should be stored inside `upload folder`.

Answer (score 0):

// use this code in php page...
   it's used to upload all file

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])!=""){
  $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
  $temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $caption1=$_POST['caption'];
  $link=$_POST['link'];
  move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name);

}
```

Comment: @ NimeSH Patel : what is this `$caption1=$_POST['caption'];
  $link=$_POST['link'];` and i dont have submit function on the form.I am using click event.